# Scilab: How to plot iterating different colors

Tags: plot, scilab

I have a pair of matrices 'RejectedEv_t' and 'RejectedEv_values' of the same size. Each row has a secuence of values, 'RejectedEv_t' has the time and 'RejectedEv_values' has the values. The number of rows changes, but is around 3 to 15 rows generally. I want to plot each row with a different color in the same graph.

I can do it manually with something like this:

```
scf();
plot(RejectedEv_t(1, :), RejectedEv_values(1, :), ".red")
plot(RejectedEv_t(2, :), RejectedEv_values(2, :), ".blue")
...
plot(RejectedEv_t(N, :), RejectedEv_values(N, :), ".<SomeColor>")
```

But I don't know how to do it in a FOR loop, specially because I don't know before hand how many rows I will have. The part of the loop I don't know how to implement is th  part:

```
[rows, cols] = size(RejectedEv_t);
for colNumber = 1:cols
    plot(RejectedEv_t(colNumber, :), RejectedEv_L2Latency(colNumber, :), ".<SomeColor>")

end
```

Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [colormap](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/colormap.html) to set the foreground color using an index. See also the other [polyline_properties](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/polyline_properties.html) you can control.

```
[rows, cols] = size(RejectedEv_t);
for colNumber = 1:cols
    plot(RejectedEv_t(colNumber, :), RejectedEv_L2Latency(colNumber, :))
    last_line = gce()
    last_line.children.foreground = colNumber
end
```